# How to return data from another ReactJS file that is being sent back from server with socket.io

Tags: reactjs, sockets

To make my project a bit tidy, I put my socket.io functions in another ReactJs file. I am trying to return the data from the socket.io function in my socketIOClient file to one of my app container.

SocketIOClient.js

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'

const socket = io.connect(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}`)  

export const studentFunction = (studentID) => {
  socket.emit('getStudentDetails', {studentID})

  socket.on('returnedStudentDetails', data => {
    return data    //obviously this is not working
  })
}
```

How do I return data from studentFunction(1)?

Container.js

```
render(){
let studentDetails = studentFunction(1)
console.log(studentDetails)

  return(
     .......
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your socket responses are callback based. So there are two approaches to solving that. Either promisify your callbacks or pass in a callback (function) from the component that would setState with the new data. Ill explain the two approaches below

### Promisify Approach

SocketIOClient.js

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'

const socket = io.connect(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}`)

export const studentFunction = (studentID) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    socket.on('returnedStudentDetails', data => {
      resolve(data);
    });
    socket.emit('getStudentDetails', { studentID });
  });
};
```

Container.js

```
import { studentFunction } from 'SocketIOClient';
export default class Container extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      studentDetails: '',
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const studentDetails = await studentFunction(1);
    this.setState({ studentDetails });
  }

  render() {
    const { studentDetails } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>{studentDetails}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

---

### Callback Approach

SocketIOClient.js

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'

const socket = io.connect(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}`)

export const studentFunction = (studentID, callback) => {
  socket.emit('getStudentDetails', { studentID })

  socket.on('returnedStudentDetails', callback)
}
```

Container.js

```
import { studentFunction } from 'SocketIOClient';
export default class Container extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      studentDetails: '',
    }
    studentFunction(1, this.onLoadStudentData);
  }

  onLoadStudentData = (studentDetails) => this.setState({ studentDetails })

  render() {
    const { studentDetails } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>{studentDetails}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried the callback version but it is running non stop and crashes the browser however the promisify approach works. Promisify is so useful and I am reading blogs about it.